# groovy error installation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i'm installling ROS-G
but when i run

```
sudo rosdep init
```

i get the next error:

```
ERROR: cannot download default sources list from:
https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
Website may be down.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54924/groovy-error-installation/) by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2013-02-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just try again.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-02-11**:
This is not uncommon for github calls.  Ticketed for retrying at: https://github.com/ros/rosdep/issues/219